# Javascript timer page refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies, countdown

I have a timer set to countdown from 10 minutes. I need it so when the user refreshes the page it does not reset the timer. Here is my javascript.

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var start = Date.now(),
    diff,
    minutes,
    seconds;
function timer() {
    // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
    // startTimer() was called
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

    if (diff <= 0) {
        // add one second so that the count down starts at the full     duration
        // example 05:00 not 04:59
        start = Date.now() + 1000;
    }
};
// we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
timer();
setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
var fiveMinutes = 60 * 10,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

Comment: im curious did you want your timer to account for the time that it also takes to refresh the page or simply to resume from where it left off?

Comment: I would like it to account for the time it takes to refresh the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 2019. I'd highly suggest using localStorage or sessionStorage instead of cookies.

```
const start = localStorage.getItem('startTime') || Date.now();
// ...rest of your code...
window.onload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('startTime', start);
    // ...rest of your code...
};
```

You may want to put the `localStorage.setItem` bit inside your `startTimer` function, after you set the value of `start`. Depends on the details of what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried doing what you suggested but it resets the timer on page refresh. Here is a my codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mZJPVG

Comment: @sizemattic `sessionStorge` is the only way to do it with nothing more than JS. the value does persist after page refreshes with `sessionStorage`, but it will not persist if you close the tab (or open a new tab? which initiates a new session)

Comment: @sizemattic In your codepen, you're setting the localStorage to a value of `start` before you've initialized the value of `start` in the first place. So it's just getting saved as undefined.

Comment: @Anthony sessionStorage gets cleared when you close the entire browser. localStorage doesn't get cleared until the user clears it themselves. So localStorage is probably better for this use case.

Comment: yes, youre right. i assumed he was correct when he said that it resets upon refresh, which i only just now tested and realized hes wrong